# Finding a decreasing sequence of positive real numbers

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $\{x_n\}$ be a decreasing sequence of positive real numbers which converges to $0$. Then there exists $m_0\in\mathbb N$ and a constant $S(m_0)>0$ depending on $m_0$ such that $|x_{j+m_0}-x_{j+m_0+1}|\geq\frac{S(m_0)x_{j+1}}{\log^2x_{j+1}}$ for all $j$.

I could not find such a sequence till now. Is such a sequence exists?

Comment: I assume $S(m_0) > 0$, as otherwise the solution is obvious.

Comment: yes,  you can. @eyeballfrog

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example. Consider $x_n = \frac{1}{2^n}$, then we see that
\begin{align}
x_{m_0+j}-x_{m_0+j+1} = \frac{1}{2^{m_0+j+1}}= \frac{1}{2^{m_0}}x_{j+1}>\frac{1}{2^{m_0}}\frac{x_{j+1}}{\log^2 x_{j+1}}
\end{align}
where the last inequality comes from the observation that $\log^2 x_{j+1}\rightarrow \infty$ as $j\rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: Here get strict inequality. Can you find any other examples? @Jacky

Comment: What are you looking for?

Comment: I'm looking for the sequence involve with log, If possible. Basically, I'm trying to find a sequence except 1/2^n.